# using matplotlib visualize two pandas dataframes in a single scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two pandas data frames having same column names.

Dataframe 1:

[image: Dataframe 1]

Dataframe 2:

[image: Dataframe 2]

1. Both the data frames have same column names. I need to visualize
   both the dfs in same scatter plot where X-axis would be values
   present in the 'function' column i.e D1_1_2, D1_2_3 etc
2. Single scatter plot is required for all the entries(or labels) ex:
   'D1_1_2', 'D1_2_3' etc , in the 'function' column as X-axis. Y-axis can dynamically pick the numeric values.
3. Different colors for both data frame values.
4. Add spacing or jitters between overlapping values.

Need support in this.

[image: Expected output:]

Comment: Which variable are you expecting in the y-axis? Can you please show an expected output from your original data?

Comment: I have added the image of the expected output and Y axis will have the dynamic numeric values. for ex: based on the input data D1_1_2 label will have values shown as 39736, 0.0 1.37 etc shown on the Y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With below example you might get an idea on how to do what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
index = ["D1_1-2", "D1_2-3", "D1_3-4"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"count": [10, 20, 25]}, index=index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"count": [15, 11, 30]}, index=index)
ax = df1.plot(style='ro', legend=False)
df2.plot(style='bo',ax=ax, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

The key is asking plot of `df2` to use the axis from plot of `df1`.

The plot you get for this is as follows:
[image]

**Aproach with jitter:**

If you want to add jitter to your data one approach can be as follows, where instead of using the previous plot axis we concatenate the dataframes and iterate over it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
index = ["D1_1-2", "D1_2-3", "D1_3-4", "D1_4-5", "D1_5-6", "D1_6-7", "D1_7-8", "D1_8-9", "D1_1-3", "D1_2-3", "D1_3-5", "D1_5-7"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"count": [10, 20, 25, 30, 32, 35, 25, 15, 5, 17, 11, 2]}, index=index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"count": [15, 11, 30, 30, 20, 30, 25, 27, 5, 16, 11, 5]}, index=index)

#We ensure we use different column names for df1 and df2
df1.columns = ["count1"]
df2.columns = ["count2"]

#We concatenate the dataframes
df = pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1)

#Function to add jitter to the array
def rand_jitter(arr):
    stdev = .01*(max(arr)-min(arr))
    return arr + np.random.randn(len(arr)) * stdev

# We iterate between the two columns of the concatenated dataframe
for i,d in enumerate(df):
    y = df[d]
    arr = range(1,len(y)+1)
    x = rand_jitter(arr)
    plt.plot(x, y, mfc = ["red","blue"][i], mec='k', ms=7, marker="o", linestyle="None")

# We set the ticks as the index labels and rotate the labels to avoid overlapping
plt.xticks(arr, index, rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Finally this results on following graph:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @cedric this code is helpful however there are few issues I am facing. 1. when I include around 40 indexes(or labels) on X-axis then many of these are not shown. So how can i show all the indexes on X-axis.  2. many corresponding values on both the data frames are over lapping , how can I add some spacing(or jitters) between the overlapping values.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a link with actual data you are working with?

Comment: @GyanendraVerma Please see updated answer with jitter added to the graph.

Comment: @GyanendraVerma was the answer helpful and was what you expected? If so please consider to upvote and/or mark as accepted ;)

Comment: sorry I got stuck with some other task so could not check that before...I checked it now and it is working for me..thank you for the help...again sorry for being late in the reply.

Comment: @GyavendraVerma please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and consider to apply it here if you think so.